# Scraping specific 'dd' tags with BeautifulSoup and Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im learning beautifulsoup and I came a cross one problem. Thats scraping `dd` tags in html. Check out the picture below, I want to get the parameters that are in the red color zone. The problem is I do not know how to access them. I have tried this:

```
    kvadratura = float(nek_html.find('span', class_='d-inline-block mt-auto').text.split(' ')[0])
    jedinica_mere = nek_html.find('span', class_='d-inline-block mt-auto').text.split(' ')[1].strip()
...
```

[image]

But the problem is that  sometimes different pages have different parameters, or different order of parameters so I cant access with index. Check out the links:

https://www.nekretnine.rs/stambeni-objekti/stanovi/centar-zmaj-jovina-salonac-id1003/NkmUEzjEFo0/

https://www.nekretnine.rs/stambeni-objekti/stanovi/prodajemo-stan-milica-od-macve-mirijevo-46m2-nov/NkNruPymNHy/

How can I sure that I will always scrape the parameter that I want?
Each parameter goes into the list afterwards so If some parameter does now exist, it should add `''` to the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such cases, this is something you might wanna do instead of using index as the latter may lead you to the wrong dd. When you go for the following approach, all you need to do is replace the text within `:contains('')` to get their dd, as in `Transakcija`,`Vrsta stana` and so on..

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.nekretnine.rs/stambeni-objekti/stanovi/zemun-krajiska-41m-bela-fasadna-cila-odlican/NkiRX4sq4Cy/"

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
Kategorija = soup.select_one(".base-inf .dl-horozontal:has(:contains('Kategorija:')) > dd")
Kategorija = Kategorija.get_text(strip=True) if Kategorija else ""
print(Kategorija)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried to use Ctrl+F to find the element on the page but I got 0 results `.base-inf .dl-horozontal:has(:contains('Kategorija:')) > dd`. I can only find this `.base-inf .dl-horozontal` ..!! .. In fact the link in the post I think not correct so I tried another link `https://www.nekretnine.rs/stambeni-objekti/stanovi/prodajemo-stan-milica-od-macve-mirijevo-46m2-nov/NkNruPymNHy/` but the same problem for me (I couldn't find the element).. The weird is that I got a result from the code you posted but I can't get the structure of the css selector

Comment: Check out the edit along with the link used @YasserKhalil .

Comment: Thanks a lot for response. I know the code is working very well (I am sure of your great skills). What I am trying to get is the CSS Selector .. When I used Ctrl + F in the developer tools in Chrome to find `.base-inf .dl-horozontal:has(:contains('Kategorija:')) > dd`, I got no results. Why?

Comment: Did you check the url that I've edited before long?

Comment: Yes I did. I can find the element in that way `.base-inf .dl-horozontal > dd` and that returns the same result .. but I can't get why I can't find the pattern you put in the code through developer tools

Comment: Check out this [image](https://filebin.ca/59DmRz8VhxD5/Untitled.jpg).

Comment: Now I got your question. You can't find the exact pattern using dev tools only because it is psudo selectors that I've used.

Comment: Btw, would you care to give [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59794830/unable-to-populate-unique-values-in-third-sheet-comparing-the-values-of-the-seco) a go to offer any solution the way it has been described in the first place?