# Unable to populate unique values in third sheet comparing the values of the second sheet to the first one

Tags: excel, vba

I've got three sheets - `main`,`specimen` and `output` in an excel workbook. The sheet `main` and `speciment` contain some information. Some of the information in two sheets are identical but few of them are not. My intention is to paste those information in `output` which are available in `speciment` but not in `main`.

I've tried like [currently it fills in lots of cells producing duplicates]:

```
Sub getData()
    Dim cel As Range, celOne As Range, celTwo As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("main")
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("specimen")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("output")


    For Each cel In ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row)
        For Each celOne In ws1.Range("A2:A" & ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row)
            If cel(1, 1) <> celOne(1, 1) Then ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).value = celOne(1, 1)
        Next celOne
    Next cel
End Sub
```

`main` contains:

```
UNIQUE ID   FIRST NAME          LAST NAME
A0000477    RICHARD NOEL        AARONS 
A0001032    DON WILLIAM         ABBOTT 
A0290191    REINHARDT WESTER    CARLSON 
A0290284    RICHARD WARREN      CARLSON 
A0002029    RAYMOND MAX         ABEL 
A0002864    DARRYL SCOTT        ABLING 
A0003916    GEORGES YOUSSEF     ACCAOUI
```

`specimen` contains:

```
UNIQUE ID   FIRST NAME       LAST NAME
A0288761    ROBERT HOWARD    CARLISLE 
A0290284    RICHARD WARREN   CARLSON 
A0290688    THOMAS A         CARLSTROM 
A0002029    RAYMOND MAX      ABEL 
A0002864    DARRYL SCOTT     ABLING
```

`output` should contain [***EXPECTED***]:

```
UNIQUE ID   FIRST NAME      LAST NAME
A0288761    ROBERT HOWARD   CARLISLE 
A0290688    THOMAS A        CARLSTROM
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the latest version of Excel, with the `FILTER` function and dynamic arrays, you can do this with an Excel formula.

I changed your Main and Specimen data into tables.

On the Output worksheet you can then enter this formula into a single cell:

```
=FILTER(specTbl,ISNA(MATCH(specTbl[UNIQUE ID],mnTbl[UNIQUE ID],0)))
```

The remaining fields will autopopulate with the results.

For a VBA solution, I like to use Dictionaries, and VBA arrays for speed.

```
'set reference to microsoft scripting runtime
'  or use late-binding
Option Explicit
Sub findMissing()
    Dim wsMain As Worksheet, wsSpec As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim dN As Dictionary, dM As Dictionary
    Dim vMain As Variant, vSpec As Variant, vOut As Variant
    Dim I As Long, v As Variant

With ThisWorkbook
    Set wsMain = .Worksheets("Main")
    Set wsSpec = .Worksheets("Specimen")
    Set wsOut = .Worksheets("Output")
End With

'Read data into vba arrays for processing speed
With wsMain
    vMain = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=3)
End With

With wsSpec
    vSpec = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=3)
End With

'add ID to names dictionary
Set dN = New Dictionary
For I = 2 To UBound(vMain, 1)
    dN.Add Key:=vMain(I, 1), Item:=I
Next I

'add missing ID's to missing dictionary
Set dM = New Dictionary
For I = 2 To UBound(vSpec, 1)
    If Not dN.Exists(vSpec(I, 1)) Then
        dM.Add Key:=vSpec(I, 1), Item:=WorksheetFunction.Index(vSpec, I, 0)
    End If
Next I

'write results to output array
ReDim vOut(0 To dM.Count, 1 To 3)
    vOut(0, 1) = "UNIQUE ID"
    vOut(0, 2) = "FIRST NAME"
    vOut(0, 3) = "LAST NAME"
I = 0
For Each v In dM.Keys
    I = I + 1
    vOut(I, 1) = dM(v)(1)
    vOut(I, 2) = dM(v)(2)
    vOut(I, 3) = dM(v)(3)
Next v

Dim R As Range
With wsOut
    Set R = .Cells(1, 1)
    Set R = R.Resize(UBound(vOut, 1) + 1, UBound(vOut, 2))

    With R
        .EntireColumn.Clear
        .Value = vOut
        .Style = "Output"
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Both show the same result (except the formula solution does not bring over the column headers; but you can do that with a formula `=mnTbl[#Headers]` in the cell above the original formula above).

[image]

Comment: I didn't have option to test your code yet. I'll let you know once I do that. Thanks.

Comment: The script throws this error `Named argument not found` pointing at this line `dN.Add key:=vMain(I, 1), item:=I`.

Comment: @robots.txt It works fine here whether I use early or late-binding.  Did you change anything at all in the code I provided?

Comment: @robots.txt You wouldn't happen to be using Excel for Mac?

Comment: I'm using Excel in windows @Ron.

Comment: @robots.txt The error doesn't make sense to me.  It implies that either `key` or `item` are not valid arguments for the `Dictionary` object, and that's just not the case. If you go to your Object Browser, and navigate to Scripting/Dictionary/Add, do you see `Sub Add(Key, Item)
    Member of Scripting.Dictionary
    Add a new key and item to the dictionary.`

Comment: Okay, I got it sorted. Defining `Dim dN As New Scripting.Dictionary` seems to have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to join the values of each row in each range and store them in arrays.

Then compare arrays and output the unique values.

In this case, your uniques come from evaluating the whole row, and not just the Unique ID.

Please read code's comments and adjust it to fit your needs.

```
Public Sub OutputUniqueValues()

    Dim mainSheet As Worksheet
    Dim specimenSheet As Worksheet
    Dim outputSheet As Worksheet

    Dim mainRange As Range
    Dim specimenRange As Range

    Dim mainArray As Variant
    Dim specimenArray As Variant

    Dim mainFirstRow As Long
    Dim specimenFirstRow As Long

    Dim outputCounter As Long

    Set mainSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("main")
    Set specimenSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("specimen")
    Set outputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("output")

    ' Row at which the output range will be printed (not including headers)
    outputCounter = 2

    ' Process main data ------------------------------------

    ' Row at which the range to be evaluated begins
    mainFirstRow = 2

    ' Turn range rows into array items
    mainArray = ProcessRangeData(mainSheet, mainFirstRow)


    ' Process specimen data ------------------------------------

    ' Row at which the range to be evaluated begins
    specimenFirstRow = 2

    ' Turn range rows into array items
    specimenArray = ProcessRangeData(specimenSheet, specimenFirstRow)

    ' Look for unique values and output results in sheet
    OutputUniquesFromArrays outputSheet, outputCounter, mainArray, specimenArray

End Sub

Private Function ProcessRangeData(ByVal dataSheet As Worksheet, ByVal firstRow As Long) As Variant


    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim evalRowRange As Range

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim counter As Long

    Dim dataArray As Variant

    ' Get last row in sheet (column 1 = column A)
    lastRow = dataSheet.Cells(dataSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Set the range of specimen sheet
    Set dataRange = dataSheet.Range("A" & firstRow & ":C" & lastRow)

    ' Redimension the array to the number of rows in range
    ReDim dataArray(dataRange.Rows.Count)

    counter = 0

    ' Join each row values so it's easier to compare them later and add them to an array
    For Each evalRowRange In dataRange.Rows

        ' Use Trim function if you want to omit the first and last characters if they are spaces
        dataArray(counter) = Trim(evalRowRange.Cells(1).Value) & "|" & Trim(evalRowRange.Cells(2).Value) & "|" & Trim(evalRowRange.Cells(3).Value)

        counter = counter + 1

    Next evalRowRange

    ProcessRangeData = dataArray

End Function

Private Sub OutputUniquesFromArrays(ByVal outputSheet As Worksheet, ByVal outputCounter As Long, ByVal mainArray As Variant, ByVal specimenArray As Variant)

    Dim specimenFound As Boolean
    Dim specimenCounter As Long
    Dim mainCounter As Long

    ' Look for unique values ------------------------------------

    For specimenCounter = 0 To UBound(specimenArray)

        specimenFound = False

        ' Check if value in specimen array exists in main array
        For mainCounter = 0 To UBound(mainArray)

            If specimenArray(specimenCounter) = mainArray(mainCounter) Then specimenFound = True

        Next mainCounter

        If specimenFound = False Then
            ' Write values to output sheet
            outputSheet.Range("A" & outputCounter).Value = Split(specimenArray(specimenCounter), "|")(0)
            outputSheet.Range("B" & outputCounter).Value = Split(specimenArray(specimenCounter), "|")(1)
            outputSheet.Range("C" & outputCounter).Value = Split(specimenArray(specimenCounter), "|")(2)
            outputCounter = outputCounter + 1
        End If

    Next specimenCounter
End Sub
```